# Knockout use external function in viewmodel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm new in knockout.js and I encountered some problems with the view model and external functions. I want to use in the view model, one external function declared as property inside of it.

```
    function testViewModel(i){
        self.PositionTimestamp = ko.observable((i.PositionTimestamp == null) ? '-' : moment(i.PositionTimestamp).tz(sitetz).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
        self.PositionTimestampG = ko.observable((i.PositionTimestampG == null) ? '-' : moment(i.PositionTimestampG).tz(sitetz).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
        self.IsTimeout = ko.observable(ComputeTimeout(i)); 

        self.update=function(data){
             self.PositionTimestamp((data.PositionTimestamp == null) ? '-' : moment(data.PositionTimestamp).tz(sitetz).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
             self.PositionTimestampG((data.PositionTimestampG == null) ? '-' : moment(data.PositionTimestampG).tz(sitetz).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
             self.IsTimeout(data.IsTimeout);
        }
    }
```

and this external function:

```
function ComputeTimeout(i) {
    var loct = moment().tz(sitetz);
    var lastWiFiTime; var lastGSMTime;
    var m_w = moment.tz(i.PositionTimestamp());
    var m_g = moment.tz(i.PositionTimestampG());
    lastGSMTime = loct.diff(m_g, 'seconds'); lastWiFiTime = loct.diff(m_w, 'seconds');

    if (isNaN(lastGSMTime))
        lastGSMTime = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    if (isNaN(lastWiFiTime))
        lastWiFiTime = Number.MAX_VALUE;

    if (lastGSMTime <= 30 * 60 || lastWiFiTime <= 30 * 60)
        return 0;
    if ((lastGSMTime > 30 * 60 && lastGSMTime <= 90 * 60) && (lastWiFiTime > 30 * 60 && lastWiFiTime <= 30 * 60))
        return 1;
    if (lastGSMTime > 90 * 60 && lastWiFiTime > 90 * 60)
        return 2;
}
```

and I'm getting this error: `JavaScript runtime error: Function expected`.

This is because I'm not using the function correctly in the view model?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see your markup, and also where you construct `testViewModel`? It also looks like you're missing a `var self = this` in your view model!

Comment: I have `var self = this` in the view model...there are others properties and I've forgot to put it. The PositionTimeStamp is a field from database received through a controller.

Comment: what you pass as `i` parameter to `testViewModel` ?

Comment: The informations of the current item from DB.

Comment: `var m_w = moment.tz(i.PositionTimestamp());` should be `var m_w = moment.tz(i.PositionTimestamp);`

Comment: It gives me this error `JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'PositionTimestamp' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Then i guess your `i` parameter is null. Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91090/discussion-between-alex-mihai-and-dandy).

Comment: I can't because the data is from a database through an query.
But if put `self.IsTimeout = ko.observable(ComputeTime(i));`
it brings up to me the `i` parameter and I can use `PositionTimeStamp`

Comment: And now I have again the first error.

Comment: Are you calling `testViewModel` with `new`?

Comment: No, I'm using the properties that are inside the testViewModel in another js like this: `item.PostionTimestamp()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i is not a knockout variable => PositionTimestamp is not a function

```
function ComputeTimeout(i) {
    var loct = moment().tz(sitetz);
    var lastWiFiTime; var lastGSMTime;
    var m_w = moment.tz(i.PositionTimestamp);
    var m_g = moment.tz(i.PositionTimestampG);
    lastGSMTime = loct.diff(m_g, 'seconds'); lastWiFiTime = loct.diff(m_w, 'seconds');

    if (isNaN(lastGSMTime))
        lastGSMTime = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    if (isNaN(lastWiFiTime))
        lastWiFiTime = Number.MAX_VALUE;

    if (lastGSMTime <= 30 * 60 || lastWiFiTime <= 30 * 60)
        return 0;
    if ((lastGSMTime > 30 * 60 && lastGSMTime <= 90 * 60) && (lastWiFiTime > 30 * 60 && lastWiFiTime <= 30 * 60))
        return 1;
    if (lastGSMTime > 90 * 60 && lastWiFiTime > 90 * 60)
        return 2;
}
```